# how to change content of template postion by a component in joomla

Tags: php, joomla, joomla3.0, joomla-template, joomla-component

what i need is, when component run,component change content of position.
for example when url is: index.php?option=com_test , content of position `'left' = test` and when url is: index.php?option=com_users, position show default data by modules.

i want tp change content of modules in this position too.

i have viewed  https://joomla.stackexchange.com/questions/1054/displaying-a-joomla-module-using-php but this is for view module in component.

Answer (score 0):

One way to achieve this is to install the free or paid version of [Advanced Module Manager](https://extensions.joomla.org/extension/advanced-module-manager).

You can publish multiple versions of your modules in the required module positions and control when each one is displayed via the component.